# Error builder exportar apk for android

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, kivy

Hola amigos tengo un código que maneja opencv y numpy con otras librerías resulta que cuando exporto el apk para android, y ejecuto la aplicación en android carga y se cierra de una vez realice el logcat en android y me sale el siguiente error:

```
07-04 12:12:21.207 10072 10098 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
07-04 12:12:21.283 10072 10098 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
07-04 12:12:21.434 10072 10098 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
07-04 12:12:21.434 10072 10098 I python  :    File "/home/dev-chavita/Documentos/Alcoholimtro/alcoholimetro/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 9, in <module>
07-04 12:12:21.435 10072 10098 I python  :    File "/home/dev-chavita/Documentos/Alcoholimtro/alcoholimetro/.buildozer/android/app/views/camLoad.py", line 8, in <module>
07-04 12:12:21.435 10072 10098 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
07-04 12:12:21.435 10072 10098 I python  : Python for android ended.
07-04 12:12:21.493  1674  2449 W InputDispatcher: channel '391dce6 org.test.myalcoholimetro/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
```

y tengo la siguiente configacion en .spec

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,opencv,numpy,face_recognition

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET
android.permissions = CAMERA
android.permission-group = HARDWARE_CONTROLS

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27
```

No se que pasa por que me generar error de cv2, si exporto desde .spec opencv espero me puedan ayudar amigos.